# How to intersect row and column sub-spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the connection or, intersection between row space and column space of a square matrix? how can I intersect two different sub-spaces?

Comment: The intersection of subspaces are defined precisely like the intersection of subsets, so I am not really sure what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good picture to look at when you want to visualize row/column/null spaces and their intersections:

[image]

Taken from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra).

If $A$ is square of order $n$, then both row spaces and column spaces are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that if $x$ is in the column space, then it is not in the null
space of $A^{T}$. Similarly, if $x$ is in the row space, it is not
in the null space of $A$. One way to do gain more insight is to directly
consider the null space of
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
A^{T}
\end{array}\right]
$$
since if $Bx=0$, we have that $Ax=0$ and $A^{T}x=0$. Does this
help?